# Object tag in Internet Explorer with PDF inside

Tags: html, internet-explorer, object, pdf, z-index

i have this simple html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute;">
        <div style="position:absolute; display:block; z-index:999; left:450px;">stuff</div>
    </div>
    <object data='C:/mypdf.pdf' type="application/pdf" width="500px" heigth="500px" style="z-index:1;">     
        <p>stuff</p>
        <p>stuff</p>
    </object> 

</body>
</html>
```

In internet explorer i can not make div in front of the pdf, in others browsers works well,

Any Sugestions?

**[EDIT]**

Here's a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WhitecastlePT/m2rXY/5/)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="position:absolute;">
    <div style="position:absolute; display:block; z-index:999; left:450px;">stuff</div>
  </div>
  <object type="application/pdf" width="500px" heigth="500px" style="z-index:1;">
    <param name="src" value="http://www.who.int/medicines/publications/essentialmedicines/18th_EML_Final_web_8Jul13.pdf" />
  </object>

</body>

</html>
```